# Cannot load mysqli extension

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I'm using an amazon ec2 instance.
When I try to access phpmyadmin I get the following error:

`Cannot load mysqli extension. Please check your PHP configuration. - Documentation`

It was working before, but I decided I wanted to upgrade to php 5.

I ran this command:

```
`sudo yum install -y php55-mysqlnd php55 php55-xml php55-mcrypt php55-mbstring php55-cli mysql55 mysql55-server httpd24`
```

I removed conflicts in order to get the command to run.

And now phpmyadmin does not work. I can't connect to the database anymore through my php scripts.

I have added `extension=mysqli.so` to the php.ini file and restarted apache.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Executing `sudo yum install php55-mysqli` would be my first bet.

Comment: @Marek Tried it.  The output is:
`Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package php55-mysqli available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Do u use Ubantu or Fedora ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I think when I removed conflicts, I did it somewhat blindly.
Don't do something like `yumo remove httpd*`.
Don't be lazy like me. Type in exactly what you want to remove.
For whatever reason, my server got removed within myUrl.com/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php so I had to create a new one (luckily it kept my tables though).

If anyone wants a really good reference for installing (or fixing your blunders) I've been following this: http://www.martin-brennan.com/php-mysql-and-ftp-on-an-amazon-ec2-instance/

I used that command I posted above to install php 5 in combination with that tutorial.